# Question on returning no value from method

Tags: c#

I have a function that works as intended:

```
        public IWebElement ParseTheSelectElement(string byElement, int byRandomValue)
        {
            new SelectElement(_driver.FindElement(CustomSelector.Parse(byElement))).SelectByIndex(byRandomValue);
            return null;
        }
```

I'm using Selenium to select an index from a dropdown going by an index, i don't need anything returned from the method as the code executes fine, i know if nothing is to be returned to use `void` i had to return something to avoid an error so i did `return null;` i'm trying to learn if this is the correct way to handle this?

I have no errors, i'm just really wanting to learn if this is valid, it does not look correct to me as i'm not returning anything. Thank you for any input.

Comment: You can always return `null` when the method has a return type and nothing needs to be returned. However, you need to make sure that the calling method (if you're the one who's going to be calling it) handles nulls correctly. So, it's perfectly fine to do `ParseTheSelectElement("element", 1);` but if you use `var element = ParseTheSelectElement("element", 1);` and you need to access `element`, you must first make sure it's not null. If, on the other hand, the method will _never_ return anything, using `void` would be the right way.

Comment: In your own words, what is `ParseTheSelectElement` supposed to do? When you declared it to return a `IWebElement`, what was the intent of that? What does the returned element (if any) represent? In the current situation, why is there not such an element to return?

Answer (score 2):

> I have no errors, i'm just really wanting to learn if this is valid, it does not look correct to me as i'm not returning anything.

It seems your intentions are to not return anything, rather perform an action, if that's the case, then make it a routine and or method and not a function that is intended to return something.

```
 public void ParseTheSelectElement(string byElement, int byRandomValue)
    {
        new SelectElement(_driver.FindElement(CustomSelector.Parse(byElement))).SelectByIndex(byRandomValue);
    }
```

You may be trying something like:

```
 _driver.FindElement(CustomSelector.Parse(byElement)).SelectByIndex(byRandomValue);
```

If you do the above, `FindElement` may not return an element, if so, then `SelectByIndex` would throw. With this in mind, you may want to check if the `FindElement` actually return's an element before doing anything with it.

Again, not sure though what your intentions are here, you're creating a new instance of `SelectElement`, but why, you're not doing anything with it.